# how to run a node server in an azure virtual machine permanently?

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I build a web based mobile app (using react), which I'm hosting as an Azure Web app. This website is connected to a node server, which I'm hosting using a azure virtual machine (I don't know if this is the best approach, maybe I should host this as a webapp instead of VM ?).

I'm still new to this strategie of developing a web based mobile app and connecting it to a hosted backend in the cloud so I apologize if this is a trivial question.
I'm using websockets to connect my frontend to the node server and then I consume messages. I don't have a database it is a simple application.

The steps I'm doing to run the app are:

- I connect to the Azure VM from my laptop with ssh
- run my server using `node server.js`
- When the server is runing, I can refresh my website and everything works fine

Now, the problem is that I want the node server to run all the time. However, I noticed that the server stops running when I deconnect (ssh) my laptop from the virtual machine. So I find myself doing these steps (connecting to the VM with ssh and running the server manually) each time I want to use the app.

Is there a way to do this so that the node server runs all the time without stoping? Also since I'm new to this, is this the right way to deploy frontend and backend? I assume I can't deploy both frontend and backend in the same Azure webapp or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since part of your question is around "Is there a better way?", I would answer that instead of fixing the issue in your current VM hosting :)).

To take full advantage of cloud for your applications, [PaaS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-paas) is always preferred over [IaaS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-iaas/). In this case, unless you have any specific reason, you should deploy your backend Node app in another [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) (aka Web App). Or you can consider [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) also if your node app has a small set of APIs, but it will require code update. Both support multiple platforms including node.js. Since you mentioned you are leveraging Web App for your react mobile app, so I hope you are already bit familiar with it. Also since Azure Function would require code change, so Web App is preferred this case.

Note: I omitted other solutions like [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/), [Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/) etc. for now, since currently we are talking about the problem of deploying only a single app, for which those will be overkill at this moment.

Also, to your point

> I assume I can't deploy both frontend and backend in the same Azure webapp or am I wrong?

Yes technically you can, depending on your scenario by "bundling" into a single app if both are in same platform (like Node in this case). Though whether one should do that would be an opinionated answer. But even if you keep those separate, you can still leverage single [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) for cost saving. So keeping separate like you have now is what I would suggest to maintain "separation of concern".

Comment: Thanks for the hint. One question though. As I said I'm hosting my node server now in a VM and I'm connecting my frontend to it over websockets. If I switch my node server to a webapp instead of VM, would I be able to access it with websockets? will the server IP adress & port in this case be the url of the webapp? I mean instead 12.33.21.22 as IP and 80 as port, should I copy the url of the webapp e.g http://example.azurewebsites.net/ and port 80 in my frontend code so that it connects with the node server?

Comment: Yes Web App Supports websocket (by default off, you need to turn on) https://pasteboard.co/JpnD6uf.png

Comment: Thanks! If it is so then this will solve my problem. Since the webapp will run forever and that is what I need. My problem with VM is that I need to connect and run my server manually, but if it works as a webapp that would be perfect because it will run automatically after I deploy. I ll try it out and post a feedback

Comment: Sure, keep posted and let me know in case of further question. Best of luck.

Comment: Surprisingly, this did worked somehow, but I'm getting warnings ( about SSL). Is this the right way to do it? I mean with a webapp. When I think about it, I only need the nodejs server for the websocket connection to another backend server. I don't need any HTML/CSS in the webapp therefore I'm asking myself whether this is the right way to do this

Comment: You probably meant yours is an API app without frontend. Yes, that still fits in App Service (aka Web App). [API app](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/app-service/api/) is definitely one of the first class citizens of webapp. Regarding the SSL warning, that will  need a deeper look if you can share more details.